# Relationship with geographical coordinate and Lambert coordinate?

Tags: google-maps, projection

How can I find the system of projection which Google Map works transform geographic coordinate (latitude, longitude) to Lambert coordinates (x,y) .

Just the relationship between the two coordinates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is application of a mathematical formula and has nothing to do with programming per se.

Comment: Have you researched this problem?

Answer (score -1):

According to those followed links :

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_conformal_conic_projection)

[land information](http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/projection-conversions/lambert-conformal-conic-geographic)

Let lambda be the longitude,  lambda_0 the reference longitude, phi the latitude,  phi_0 the reference latitude, and phi_1 and phi_2 the standard parallels. Then the transformation of spherical coordinates to the plane via the Lambert conformal conic projection is given by

```
x   =   rho*sin[n*(lambda-lambda_0)]    
y   =   rho_0-rho*cos[n*(lambda-lambda_0)],
```

where

```
rho =   F*cot^n((1/4)*pi+(1/2)*phi) 
rho_0   =   F*cot^n((1/4)*pi+(1/2)*phi_0)
F   =   (cos(phi_1)*tan^n((1/4)*pi+(1/2)*phi_1))/n  
n   =   (ln(cos(phi_1)*sec(phi_2)))/(ln[tan((1/4)*pi+(1/2)*phi_2)*cot((1/4)*pi+(1/2)*phi_1)])
```

reminder :

```
cot = 1/tan
sec = 1/cos
```